# How do I modify a list of dataframes to persist the changes in the original data

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I noticed that any modification that I want to perform to all the dataframes in a list doesn't modify the original data imported to the notebook unless I apply such changes to the individual dataframes in the list.
I am new to R, please is there any other way to easily apply same modification to  multiple datafames ?

```
data_frames <- list(.............)
for (df in data_frames) {
  clean_names(df)
  rename_with(df, tolower)
}
```

```
data_frames <- list(.........)

lapply(data_frames, function(df) {
  clean_names(df)
  rename_with(df, tolower)
  df
})
```

```
for (i in seq_along(data_frames)) {
  data_frames[[i]] <- clean_names(data_frames[[i]])
  data_frames[[i]] <- rename_with(data_frames[[i]], tolower)
}
```

None of these were able to modify the original data imported.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr::lst` to create a named list of dataframes and apply the functions. Then use `list2env` to transfer the changed data from list to original data.

```
data_frames <- dplyr::lst(.............)

for (i in seq_along(data_frames)) {
  data_frames[[i]] <- clean_names(data_frames[[i]])
  data_frames[[i]] <- rename_with(data_frames[[i]], tolower)
}

list2env(data_frames, .GlobalEnv)
```

Note - It is usually recommended to keep the dataframes in a list instead of creating separate dataframes in global environment. They are easier to manage/process in that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. From what you said, it seems the modified data will be transferred and not just a one-way modification of the original imported data in their variables. From what I understand, when I modified dataframes from the list, the modification persists only in that list, meaning that to continue working with the modified data, I will have to call or reference the list. So, even if I want to use just one dataframe, I will still have to call or reference it from the modified list and not just directly. Please, let me know if I am correct?

Comment: No. So if you have list of dataframes as `data_frames <- dplyr::lst(df1, df2)` and then you run `list2env(data_frames, .GlobalEnv)` you can have the modified data in `df1` and `df2` respectively. You don't need reference the list here.

Comment: I got that. Thank you